# Joining different text file to 1 text file c#

Tags: c#, file, createfile

im try to combine text file to filename. For example my path 
C:\Users\o.k\Desktop\Record\
record file has many .txt file. they names is

- 20.07.2015-1.txt
- 20.07.2015-2.txt
- 20.07.2015-3LAST_try.txt
- 20.07.2015-4.txt
- 20.07.2015-5.txt
- 20.07.2015-6LAST_a1.txt
- 20.07.2015-7FIRST_a2.txt
- 20.07.2015-8FIRST_a4.txt

this is first example write in 20.07.2015-1.txt file for example
the other one in text file 20.07.2015-2.txt this is second example.
i want to combine this 2 sentence like

- this is first example
- this is second example

create new text file then write in this 2 sentences.but this should for filename group.

```
20.07.2015-1.txt
20.07.2015-2.txt
20.07.2015-4.txt
20.07.2015-5.txt
```

this name format save together to main.txt

```
20.07.2015-3LAST_try.txt
20.07.2015-6LAST_a1.txt
```

this name format save together to LAST.txt

```
20.07.2015-7FIRST_a2.txt
20.07.2015-8FIRST_a4.txt
```

this name format save together to First.text

when click button it creates 3 type text file. Main,first and last. Main.txt file has contents of this files 20.07.2015-1.txt 20.07.2015-2.txt 20.07.2015-4.txt 20.07.2015-5.txt First.txt file has contents of this files 20.07.2015-7FIRST_a2.txt
    20.07.2015-8FIRST_a4.txt etc.

Comment: so you want both the txt files to combine and make 1 big text file?

Comment: no i want to 3 text file. main first and last.

Comment: dont understand what you need to happen

Comment: Neither do I. But to read a file you have System.IO.File.ReadAllLines and to write a file you gout System.IO.File.WriteAllLines.

Comment: Please use the `edit` link under your original post to edit it, and include an actual question.

Comment: You now have asked 3 (undeleted) questions where you have been told on each of them that this is not an acceptable way to ask a question. You need to show what you have tried/researched and why that hasn't solved your problem. Read [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (var output = File.Create("output"))
{
    foreach (var file in new[] { "file1", "file2" })
    {
        using (var input = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            input.CopyTo(output);
        }
    }
}
```